# multi level ul li backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am try to making nested navigation using backbone.js below is my code.

Json Data :

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"one","parent_id":0},
{"id":2,"name":"two","parent_id":0},
{"id":3,"name":"three","parent_id":0},
{"id":4,"name":"four","parent_id":0},
{"id":5,"name":"five","parent_id":0},
{"id":6,"name":"one","parent_id":2},
{"id":7,"name":"two","parent_id":2},
{"id":8,"name":"three","parent_id":2},
{"id":9,"name":"four","parent_id":2},
{"id":10,"name":"five","parent_id":2},
]
```

Html :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
</ul>
```

and Backbonejs code here :

```
var MenuList = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    id: 'menu-trial-task',
    initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new ItemCollection();
            this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
            this.collection.fetch();       
    },
    render: function() {
        _.each( this.collection.models, function( item ) {
            this.$el.append( new MenuItem({model:item}).render().el );
        }, this);
    $('nav').html(this.$el);    
        return this;
    }
});

var MenuItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template($('#munu_itemt_view').html());
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
        }
});     
var menuList = new MenuList();
```

and the result is :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">five</a></li>    
</ul>
```

as you can see this is not required result.

i also tried with underscore.js but failed. Is there any good and simple way to do this ?

Comment: what is your question, or at least, what's going wrong whit your code ? Also you should use templating, underscore js has a default templating engine.

Comment: Are you having issues in generating the final html?

Comment: Yes! @Waqar Alamgir i aslo added the result in my question.

Comment: @Willem D'haeseleer i edited my question. can you suggest how can i use in this condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with nested view and I would suggest using template

```
var data = [
    {"id":1,"name":"one","parent_id":0},
    {"id":2,"name":"two","parent_id":0},
    {"id":3,"name":"three","parent_id":0},
    {"id":4,"name":"four","parent_id":0},
    {"id":5,"name":"five","parent_id":0},
    {"id":6,"name":"one","parent_id":2},
    {"id":7,"name":"two","parent_id":2},
    {"id":8,"name":"three","parent_id":2},
    {"id":9,"name":"four","parent_id":2},
    {"id":10,"name":"five","parent_id":2},
]

var NestedView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( "<ul id='ul-0'></ul>" )
    this.collection.each( function( model ){ this.renderElement( model ) }, this )
  },

  renderElement: function( model ){
    var ul = this.getParentUl( model );
    this.appendElement( ul, model );
  },

  getParentUl: function( model ) {
    var ul = this.$el.find( "#ul-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) );
    if( ul.length == 0 ) {
      this.appendListInElement( model );
      ul = this.$el.find( "#ul-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) );
    }

    return ul;
  },

  appendListInElement: function( model ){
    var li = this.$el.find( "#li-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) );
    li.after( "<ul id='ul-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) + "'></ul>" );
  },

  appendElement: function( ul, model ){
    ul.append( "<li id='li-" + model.get( "id" ) + "'>" + model.get( "name" ) + "</li>" );
  }
});

var elements = new Backbone.Collection( data );
var nestedView = new NestedView({ el: "#wrapper", collection: elements });
nestedView.render();


<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Here is the complete code, with underscore template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Backbone</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>

    <script type="text/template" id="parent-template">
        <ul id='ul-<%= parent_id %>'></ul>
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="child-template">
        <li id="li-<%= id %>"><%= name %></li>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var compiledParent = _.template( $('#parent-template').html() );
    var compiledChild = _.template( $('#child-template').html() );

    var data = [
        {"id":1,"name":"one","parent_id":0},
        {"id":2,"name":"two","parent_id":0},
        {"id":3,"name":"three","parent_id":0},
        {"id":4,"name":"four","parent_id":0},
        {"id":5,"name":"five","parent_id":0},
        {"id":6,"name":"one","parent_id":2},
        {"id":7,"name":"two","parent_id":2},
        {"id":8,"name":"three","parent_id":2},
        {"id":9,"name":"four","parent_id":2},
        {"id":10,"name":"five","parent_id":2},
    ];

    var NestedView = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(){
        this.$el.html( compiledParent({parent_id : '0'}) );
        this.collection.each( function( model ){ this.renderElement( model ) }, this )
      },

      renderElement: function( model ){
        var ul = this.getParentUl( model );
        this.appendElement( ul, model );
      },

      getParentUl: function( model ) {
        var ul = this.$el.find( "#ul-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) );
        if( ul.length == 0 ) {
          this.appendListInElement( model );
          ul = this.$el.find( "#ul-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) );
        }

        return ul;
      },

      appendListInElement: function( model ){
        var li = this.$el.find( "#li-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) );
        li.after( compiledParent({parent_id : model.get( "parent_id" )}) );
      },

      appendElement: function( ul, model ){
        ul.append( compiledChild({id:model.get( "id" ) , name:model.get( "name" )}) );
      }
    });

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var elements = new Backbone.Collection( data );
        var nestedView = new NestedView({ el: "#wrapper", collection: elements });
        nestedView.render();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried to implement you answer but nothing display and does not show any error.

it just displaying `<ul id='ul-null'></ul>`

Comment: How you are calling your js? <div id="wrapper"></div> should be considered on top

Comment: yes that was on the top and result was `<div id="wrapper"><ul id='ul-null'></ul></div>`

Comment: @Furqan I have putted the whole working code, If you like my answer and solves your problem then don't forget to accept it.

Comment: If you need explanation I can help you with that as well! If you are new to Backbone.js I'll seriously ask you to look at knockout.js

Comment: yes bro i am new to Backbone.js. i used @Willem D'haeseleer's solution  and i am facing issue. this function unbinding the backbone view events.

now your code is working. how can i do this using underscore templates. also please explain your code. i want to solve this issue forever.

Comment: with this code view events are working fine.
1 more question. whay you use `this.$el.html( "<ul id='ul-0'></ul>" )` one first line of render function. can i use `tagName:'ul'` ?

Comment: I have updated the code you will now find _ templating, since it is nested it is to be done in that way only, the basic idea to use this.$el is that you can append menu to any html element.

Comment: JazakAllah for great answer :)

Comment: Hi @Waqar Alamgir,
one problem its binding 1 event 2 time on sub list.
here you can check http://plnkr.co/avG9h3

Comment: I think you need to bind event in appendElement method, use jQuery to that.

Comment: yes! but this is not the good solution. we should backbone events.

Comment: You can do something like this events:{ 'click ul#parent-item-0 > li':'liClicked' }

Answer (score 1):

How about this, i think it's better to build your json as you would want the menu.

You should also not forget to put your nested `ul` inside an `li` as well, other wise it isn't valid.

It doesn't use templating like i said you could do but i think it does the job well enough.
It requires only jquery to work.

```
var menu = [
    {name:"one"},
    {
        name:"two",
        nodes: [
            {name:"one"},
            {name:"two"},
            {name:"three"},
            {name:"four"},
            {name:"five"}
        ]
    },
    {name:"three"},
    {name:"four"},
    {name:"five"}
];

function createMenu(menuItem)
{
    var list = $("<ul>");
    $.each (menuItem, function(indexInArray, currentItem){
        var li = $("<li>").html(currentItem.name);
        if (currentItem.nodes)
            li.append(createMenu(currentItem.nodes));
        list.append(li);
    });
    return list;
}

$("body").append(createMenu(menu));
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3gjkZ/2/

Comment: i played with this answer but looks awesome :) let me implement this.

Comment: Glad you like it, i removed the underscore dependency, you only need jQuery now ;)
Make sure to accept the answer if it helped you out !

Comment: i am using this function and facing an issue :( this function unbinding the backbone view events.

Comment: post the view so that we can see why.

Answer (score 1):

change render like this:

```
render: function() {
   this.$el.html( this.template( items : this.model.toJSON()));
   return this;
}
```

and teplate like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">${name}</a>
      <ul> {each items}
          <li><a href="#">${name}</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

i use jquery template, you can change it to underscore